# Spring Boot application on App Engine errors while using servlet filters

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, filter

I'm building a simple web application using spring boot + app engine.
I've followed the guidelines suggested in the [getting started github page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard) and everything was working fine until I've tried to implement a simple Filter:

```
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
                         ServletResponse servletResponse,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.info("TESST");
    }
}
```

configured with the web.xml page in plain servlet fashion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>eu.project.docscatalog.filters.AuthFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

(I've also tried with the @Component annotation like you usually would do in a spring application)

When I launch the application with mvn appengine:run the web server starts but with the following error message:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2019-06-03 10:28:07.956:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context c.g.a.t.d.j.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@a85644c{/,file:///C:/Users/Pierluigi/Desktop/source/docs-catalog/target/docs-catalog-1-0-0/,UNA
VAILABLE}{C:\Users\Pierluigi\Desktop\source\docs-catalog\target\docs-catalog-1-0-0}
[INFO] GCLOUD: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:136)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:750)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:744)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:368)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:852)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:415)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:343)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:283)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:282)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:223)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:221)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:221)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:404)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:257)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:248)
```

The filter doesn't work, I thought it could be something related to the provided tomcat, and be caused by some duplicate dependencies, however I can't find what is causing the problem. My pom contains the following dependencies:

```
 <dependencies>
        <!--Spring boot components-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-datastore</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Standard dep-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Provided-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Test related-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Someone has any idea what is going on ? 
I would be really thankful to anyone giving an hand :)

Comment: AbstractMethodError -> `Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method.
 Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can
 only occur at run time if the definition of some class has
 incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last
 compiled` Have you checked your compilation targets?

Comment: It happens, due to a discrepancy in the `servlet-api` version. Can you quickly run `mvn dependency:tree` on your local and compare the version of `servlet-api` and the scope ( it would be provided, most probably) and check the `servlet-api` version on the tomcat version you are using on app engine?

Comment: @Saheb thank you for the suggestion, it seems I don't have that specific dependency servlet-api, might this be the problem ? it doesn't seem to be a dependency from spring-boot-starter-tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it.

I didn't follow the [getting started page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard) correctly.

I've to exclude spring-boot-starter-tomcat from spring-boot-starter-web and include servlet-api.

Thanks @Saheb for pointing me to the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

This post might help someone who face similar issue like below.

I got similar error java.lang.AbstractMethodError but no where mentioned the real cause. This error happened when deploying spring boot application in app engine flexible environment. **Cause is slf4j library**.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:136)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:750)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:744)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:369)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:854)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:192)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:510)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:153)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:172)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:430)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:65)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:598)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:240)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:119)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$0(XmlConfiguration.java:1797)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1746)
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:136)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:750)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:744)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:369)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:854)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:192)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:510)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:153)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:172)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:430)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:65)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:598)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:240)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:119)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$0(XmlConfiguration.java:1797)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1746)
```